# nodejs mongoDB connection login page

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

When I send username, password, email by postman it works and adds infos to mongodb schema but in login page at react it doesn't work. I would really appreciate if someone could help. Thank you so much.

[console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2vQwH.png)

**React logic:**

```
const [username, setUserName] = useState("");
const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
    
const handleSubmit = async (e) =>{
  console.log(".....");
     e.preventDefault();
    const res =  await axios.post("/auth/register", {
     username,
     email,
     password,
    });
    console.log(res)
    };
```

**Node.js logic:**

```js
router.post("/register", async (req, res) => {
  
  console.log("here")
      try{   
          const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
          const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, salt);

          const newUser = new User({
            username: req.body.username,
            email: req.body.email,
            password: hashedPassword,
            });

      const user = await newUser.save(); 
      res.status(200).json(user);
      } catch(err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
        
    }
);


/////////////////////

app.use("/api/auth", authRoute);


app.use("/",(req,res)=>{
    console.log("main url")
})

app.listen("3000",()=>{
    console.log("backend running");
})
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure that you send the request to the right route/server,
maybe you miss-typed the port or the route itself.

Comment: I checked but couldn't find anything. The thing is it's not showing 404 error anymore but nothing happens either just console log print. Thank you so much for comment.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this line `const res =  await axios.post("/auth/register", {` isn't matching your backend `app.use("/api/auth", authRoute);`

Comment: const res =  await axios.post("/register", { 
  unfortunately nothing has changed  after this and I have no other idea tbh.

Comment: Your node Route is `("/api/auth")`  while your Axios is making the request to `/auth/register`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you defined your register logic on `/register` endpoint, BUT you are sending request to `/auth/register` endpoint.

Try to change your React logic to send request to `/register` endpoint:

```js
const res =  await axios.post("/register", {
  username,
  email,
  password,
});
```

Comment: unfortunately nothing has changed  after deleting auth and I have no other idea tbh.